# Simple commerce text input own price

Tags: simple-commerce, price-modifier

Simple commerce permit to define fixed prices.

```
{item_regular_price}
{item_sale_price}
```

But no have options, like a form text input, where the user could digit this own price, for a donation.

It possible to achieve this ?

I'm using EE4, it could be achieve with the great Cartthrob,but is not yet EE4  compatible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems no have options to insert  form text input, where the own valor could be entered.

As a temporary solution, a simple Paypal button was inserted.